# Github Commit Failing After New Update

Tags: github

I've been trying to make new commits for and publish my project but I keep getting this error:

[image]

What is the solution to this issue because I can't figure out what the error means?

Comment: I would recommend you to re-install git on your machine and then try it again.

Comment: I tried this already as well as using an older version of git/github desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this bug followed in [issue 2041](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/2041).

```
Error: write EOF
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:804:14)
```

One possible cause is the **[path length](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/2041#issuecomment-317487970)**: make sure your repo is cloned near C:\, for testing.